# Check if ID is referenced in anoter tables

Tags: sql

This SQL Query results in a list:

```
SELECT COUNT(zzpricing.PRICETITLEID),
        ZZPRICETITLE.PRICETITLEID, 
        ZZPRICETITLE.CHARACTERID,
        ZZPRICETITLE.SOURCEID,
        ZZPRICETITLE.CALCULATIONTYPE,
        ZZPRICETITLE.COMPUTEDPRICETITLEIND,
        ZZPRICETITLE.ONEDAYIND,
        ZZPRICETITLE.EXPRESSION
        FROM ZZPRICETITLE 
    LEFT JOIN ZZPRICING ON ZZPRICETITLE.PRICETITLEID = ZZPRICING.PRICETITLEID
   Group BY ZZPRICETITLE.PRICETITLEID, 
        ZZPRICETITLE.CHARACTERID,
        ZZPRICETITLE.SOURCEID,
        ZZPRICETITLE.CALCULATIONTYPE,
        ZZPRICETITLE.COMPUTEDPRICETITLEIND,
        ZZPRICETITLE.ONEDAYIND,
        ZZPRICETITLE.EXPRESSION;
```

Now I want to expand this list with a column named REFERENCED which marks the `PRICETITLEID's` which have never been used from the following tables;

- ZZEXTVALUATIONRULE
- ZZMARKET
- ZZMARKETUSE
- ZZPRICE
- ZZTRADE
- ZZVALUATIONRULE
- ZZPRICING

Values should “**Yes**” if the `pricetitle` has been used, and “**No**” if it hasn’t.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` those tables, and use a `CASE` expression to check for `NULL`.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, table aliases are very convenient when having long table names